# eclipse open declaration not working properly

Tags: c++, eclipse, unix, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse 4.6, with C++ project in linux.
if it's relevant:
Compilation is done via CMake makefile.
Gdb version is 8.0.1

when using F3 (open declaration), 
a window is **opened with class declarations(e.g. friend class declaration), but not the class definition (i.e. class MyClass : public BaseClass...)**.

Also find all references is not working.

I have

1. used Project->index->rebuild
2. verified that the C++ General/Patch and Symbols/Path is defined properly

here is my indexer settings
[image: indexer settings]

Answer (score 4):

Turn off scalability option:

**Window -> Preferences.**

[image]

Comment: This finally fixed it for me. What a confusing default behavior...

Answer (score 0):

check if in Paths and Symbols (also in C/C++ General) your Project is added in Includes. 
If not: Go to Add... Button then Workspace... then select your workspace. It will be included as *Is a workspace path*. Maybe this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That might be because your C/C++ project makes reference to resources from other projects.

1. On the top menu bar, go to **Project -> Properties**
2. A properties window will appear. On the left side menu, go to **Project References**.
3. On the box to the right, verify if other projects are listed and check the ones that might be related to yours.
4. Press **Apply and Close** button.
5. Try on your shortcuts again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Eclipse Indexer is active
or not!! try this route

- Basic Tabs ---> Window ---> Preference ---> C/C++ ---> Indexer

and enable the indexer with all its options

[eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)